Reusing react component across the three and deduplicate request - NextJS or React
I'm using NextJS 14 and I'm making a chat application.
Each time a message is sent or received, next to the chat message there is a small icon with the image representing the user that sent the image.
To achieve that goal, I have a ChatMessageUI that is responsible to render both the message and the UI. But I don't want to sent a request to the image server each time a message is received. As its the same image for the user and recipient each time.
I made a simple repro based on what I'm achieving: Using a context to pass a reused node that I'm not expecting to re-render.
import React, { useState } from "react";

let id = 0;

// eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
const CustomNode = React.memo(() => {
  // ID is incrementing, because it's duplicated node when there is a new added.
  console.log("Render node", ++id);

  return (
    // Added some fake params, to make the browser not use it's cache.
    <img
      src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?fakingsomenextImageParams=cool"
      alt="placeholder"
      width={200}
      height={200}
    />
  );
});

const reusedNode = <CustomNode />;

export const Repro: React.FC = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([reusedNode]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setList([...list, reusedNode])}>Add</button>
      {list.map((node, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          {node} {index}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

Online sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/blissful-hill-qx9v5n

Here are two things.

First you can notice that id is incrementing because each time you add a new message, a new node is "duplicated" and it's not just reusing. Maybe it's react expected behavior. Or maybe I'm missing something here. That's not the main issue.

The image sends a network request, each time even if it's the same URL. It only happens because it's a query parameter URL (which is what is used by NextJS Image component). But on large dataset, this can get very consuming. If I could reuse the node as mentioned in part 1, this could be OK. But if I'm not able to it. I would need some caching mechanism on client side to persist the image on disk and use a standard image instead.


I'm aware of https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#minimumcachettl but I guess it's managing cache on "server side" where the image are resized. The client is still querying the server and there is still bandwidth consumed for the same content.
I was wondering with a custom loader, that generate the URL without query parameters? Something like this.
Do you have any pattern, or information on anything for that issue to recommend?
Thanks

Modern browsers typically cache resources like images to optimize performance and reduce redundant network requests. If you request the same image URL multiple times, the browser will usually serve the cached version of the image, avoiding additional network requests.
You can check if the browser is caching the image and making only one request by monitoring the network activity in the developer tools. Here's how you can do it:
1. Open Developer Tools:

Press F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I to open the developer tools.

2.Go to the Network Tab:

Navigate to the "Network" tab in the developer tools to monitor network requests.

3. Reload the Page:

Reload your page to capture all network requests from the start.

4. Add New Nodes:

Click the "Add" button multiple times to add new CustomNode components

5. Check for Image Requests:

Look for the image URL in the list of network requests. If the browser is caching the image, you should see only one request to the image URL. Subsequent requests should either not appear or indicate a cache hit (e.g., with a 304 Not Modified status).


I forgot i had checkde "disable cache" in my browser tab, was also an issue ahah thanks
